# Redirect postgres from windows to linux

Tags: linux, windows, postgresql

Currently we connect to a postgres database installed on a Windows pc for our application. In a TEST environment I am trying to figure out if it is at all possible to get the postgres server on the Windows pc to then connect to a database actually installed on a linux server. The reason for this is we have a few sites running databases that are already 100gb in size with only a year of data and I want to see how much performance improvement I can do by moving it to a linux server.

Comment: [Proxy for database server/connection?](https://serverfault.com/q/184066/145545)

Answer (score 0):

Listen to your programmer (that's probably the answer you would expect on a coder's forum).

You can use postgres_fdw to access tables on a different database, but that would make your architecture more fragile and complicated, and it wouldn't show you if you can expect a performance gain from moving your database to Linux.

The main reason is that the architecture is too different for a reasonable comparison. Your data would go through the Windows server, and there will be one more client-server connection involved.

If you want to compare the performance, set up a Linux test machine and use a tool like [pgreplay](http://laurenz.github.io/pgreplay/) to compare the performance.

Full disclosure: I am the author of that tool.